# Looking for HTML5 <select> element CSS3 styling solution: no image files, cross-browser compatible

Tags: html, css, web-applications, html-select

I am looking for styling solution to apply to HTML `<select>` element (i.e. web form drop-down) as described below:

1. Pure HTML5/CSS3 implementation
2. No any reliance on Javascript or other scripting languages
3. Cross-browsers compatibility (FF/Chrome/Safari/IE10)

Currently I'm using the following CSS3 snippet for styling `<select>` element:

```
select {
    font-size:9pt;
    letter-spacing:0.07em;
    color:#808080;
    background:transparent;
    border: solid 1px #808080;
    padding:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
select option { padding: 1px 5px 1px 3px;}
select option[selected]{ color:#303030; }
select option:nth-child(even) { background-color:#e5e5e5; }
```

Sample implementation: [**here**](http://busNY.net)

I would like to find out about other available **'pure CSS3' styling options to apply to the inner button (with that little downward triangle) of HTML `<select>` element**, i.e., its background, color, border, font properties, etc.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You're looking for a styling solution... **to what**? What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish that you haven't already?

Comment: I'll comment since my answer isn't going to be a 'real' answer: it can't be done, give up now before the frustration starts. Styling form controls is a drama, and can't be done far better than some basic recoloring and borders. Implementing a JS-based dropdown is faster and looks better than CSS will do the next few browser versions at least, and it doesn't look likely to improve for a long time currently.

Comment: @animuson: I guess it was made clear enough (please read the last sentence of my post) - I am looking for the styling solution to apply to the "drop-down" button, which is a part of that control (i.e. background, color, border properties, font, etc). Btw, I've found interesting solution that is based on radio-button control used to mimic the drop-down functionality using "pure CSS3": <a href='http://pepsized.com/demo/?id=1281'>link</a>. It works, but CSS3 part is a bit lengthy. Anyway, it's the best one I've found so far. Rgds, AB

Comment: @Niels: I would agree with you that styling form controls is indeed a pain. I've personally tried tons of various solutions, but found just one to satisfy the requirement I put in my post. CSS3 spec should be revised (IMHO) to better address this quite important issue. Using javascript for styling controls is (IMHO #2) ridiculous; modern web design must adhere to the concept of separation of programming concerns, i.e. styling belongs to CSS3. My best, AB.

Comment: Found [http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-selectbox.html](http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-selectbox.html) and [http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-metro-dropdown.html](http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-metro-dropdown.html) gems when searching for how to style the <select> element.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So far, two CSS3 solutions exist pertinent to styling SELECT element, providing adequate level of customization and overall aesthetics. The following sample demonstrates both techniques; for the sake of simplicity/readability HTML5 and CSS3 parts are encapsulated in a single HTML5 file.

The first solution implements custom image placed on the pull-down button; the second one utilizes Unicode characters (can be any).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>ADVANCED CSS3 STYLING OF SELECT ELEMENT (DROP-DOWN)</title>
        <style type="text/css">

            /* SELECT W/IMAGE */
            select#selectTravelCity
            {
               width                    : 14em;
               height                   : 3.2em;
               padding                  : 0.2em 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em;
               vertical-align           : middle;
               border                   : 1px solid #e9e9e9;
               -moz-border-radius       : 0.2em;
               -webkit-border-radius    : 0.2em;
               border-radius            : 0.2em;
               box-shadow               : inset 0 0 3px #a0a0a0;
               -webkit-appearance       : none;
               -moz-appearance          : none;
               appearance               : none;
               /* sample image from the webinfocentral.com */
               background               : url(http://webinfocentral.com/Images/favicon.ico) 95% / 10% no-repeat #fdfdfd;
               font-family              : Arial,  Calibri, Tahoma, Verdana;
               font-size                : 1.1em;
               color                    : #000099;
               cursor                   : pointer;
            }
            select#selectTravelCity  option
            {
                font-size               : 1em;
                padding                 : 0.2em 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em;
            }
            select#selectTravelCity  option[selected]{ font-weight:bold}
            select#selectTravelCity  option:nth-child(even) { background-color:#f5f5f5; }
            select#selectTravelCity:hover
            {
                color                   : #101010;
                border                  : 1px solid #cdcdcd;
            }    
            select#selectTravelCity:focus {box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #404040;}

            /*SELECT W/DOWN-ARROW*/
            select#selectPointOfInterest
            {
               width                    : 185pt;
               height                   : 40pt;
               line-height              : 40pt;
               padding-right            : 20pt;
               text-indent              : 4pt;
               text-align               : left;
               vertical-align           : middle;
               box-shadow               : inset 0 0 3px #606060;
               border                   : 1px solid #acacac;
               -moz-border-radius       : 6px;
               -webkit-border-radius    : 6px;
               border-radius            : 6px;
               -webkit-appearance       : none;
               -moz-appearance          : none;
               appearance               : none;
               font-family              : Arial,  Calibri, Tahoma, Verdana;
               font-size                : 18pt;
               font-weight              : 500;
               color                    : #000099;
               cursor                   : pointer;
               outline                  : none;
            }
            select#selectPointOfInterest option
            {
                padding             : 4px 10px 4px 10px;
                font-size           : 11pt;
                font-weight         : normal;
            }
            select#selectPointOfInterest option[selected]{ font-weight:bold}
            select#selectPointOfInterest option:nth-child(even) { background-color:#f5f5f5; }
            select#selectPointOfInterest:hover {font-weight: 700;}
            select#selectPointOfInterest:focus {box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000099; font-weight: 600;}

            /*LABEL FOR SELECT*/
            label#lblSelect{ position: relative; display: inline-block;}
            /*DOWNWARD ARROW (25bc)*/
            label#lblSelect::after
            {
                content                 : "\25bc";
                position                : absolute;
                top                     : 0;
                right                   : 0;
                bottom                  : 0;
                width                   : 20pt;
                line-height             : 40pt;
                vertical-align          : middle;
                text-align              : center;
                background              : #000099;
                color                   : #fefefe;
               -moz-border-radius       : 0 6px 6px 0;
               -webkit-border-radius    : 0 6px 6px 0;
                border-radius           : 0 6px 6px 0;
                pointer-events          : none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <br />
        <select id="selectTravelCity" title="Select Travel Destination">
            <option>New York City</option>
            <option>Washington DC</option>
            <option>Los Angeles</option>
            <option>Chicago</option>
            <option>Houston</option>
            <option>Philadelphia</option>
            <option>Phoenix</option>
            <option>San Antonio</option>
            <option>San Diego</option>
            <option>Dallas</option>
            <option>San Jose</option>
            <option>Austin</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />

        <label id="lblSelect">
            <select id="selectPointOfInterest" title="Select points of interest nearby">
                <option>caffe</option>
                <option>food beverage</option>
                <option>restaurant</option>
                <option>shopping</option>
                <option>taxi limo</option>
                <option>theatre</option>
                <option>museum</option>
                <option>computers</option>
            </select>
        </label>
</body>
</html>
```

Both solutions are based on the use of CSS3 pseudo-classes. Working example is available **[here](http://webinfocentral.com)**.

Note: there is some compatibility issue with Internet Explorer, but IE is going to be deprecated, thus it should not be recommended for any future dev.

Answer (score 2):

i had used this in one of my modules.
You can try this :

```
select {
   background-color:#91EB76;
   width: 180px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   height: 34px;
}
```

Adjusting colors will do the work for you [hopefully]

- Pure HTML5/CSS3 implementation
- No any reliance on Javascript or other scripting languages
- Cross-browsers compatibility (FF/Chrome/Safari/IE10)

Comment: Sorry, but it's essentially a shorten version of my original post! You just put another values for the properties, but it does not constitute a different solution. I've clarified specifically, that I am looking for the inner button CSS3 styling, which is still not achieved. Anyway, thanks for your response. Rgds, AB