# How to Override Select List suggestion

Tags: css, html

I am working on one of core component of HTML, `select`.
Now I want to modify its drop down behavior. Mean dropdown height, scroll sytle etc.

[image]

Is there any way to override the default behavior of dropdown?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling Select Drop down box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516559/styling-select-drop-down-box)

Comment: I think no, see in this example we do not have any control on scroll style, dropdown height.  Is there any other thing that can done.

Comment: CSS can't style scroll bars for all browsers. Support is patchy, consider using an external JS / jQuery library for cross browser support.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `select` and `option` styles, for example:

```css
select {
  background-color: yellow;
}

option {
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
  <option>Option 5</option>
</select>
```

*"I want to override the css for scroll bar, dropdown container height etc."*. It seems like there is no way to do it in default HTML `select` element.

Comment: Sorry to see, but this not the solution what I am looking for. I want to override the css for scroll bar, dropdown container height etc.

Comment: @StillLearning, I have updated the answer. It seems like there is no way to do it in default HTML `select` element.